# Upload Multiple Excel file in PHPExcel

Tags: php

I am wondering how to upload multiple files using this method in php.

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']) && $_FILES['files']['error']==0) {

    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";

    $tmpfname = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    echo "<table class=\"table table-sm\">";
    echo "<tr><td scope=\"row\">";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.'1')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.'2')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.'3')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.'4')->getValue();
    echo "</td><tr>";
    echo "</table>";    
}
```

I think foreach is the solution but I don't know how to write it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried with foreach so far?

Comment: Hi, foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $val ){

        $tmpfname = $val;
    }

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for answer on how Upload Multiple Excel file in PHPExcel try this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitexcel'])){
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
echo count($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']);

foreach ($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'] as $value){

    $tmpfname = $value;
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    echo "<table class=\"table table-sm\">";
    echo "<tr><td scope=\"row\">";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.'1')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.'2')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.'3')->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.'4')->getValue();
    echo "</td><tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitexcel"/>
</form>
```

this is just to get the concept on getting the content of each excel files so you can modify it before saving into databse.